# Inno Setup - Move the password page before the welcome page (first page)

Tags: inno-setup

If I use:

```
[setup]
Password=mypass
```

The password page is after the welcome page and the license page.

How to move the password page before the welcome page? (at first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change order of the standard pages. Nor you can create a custom page before the "welcome" page.

Your options are:

- Ask for the password using a separate custom form.

  You can use the same code as [@vicsar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386354/850848#37602073) to the [Password protected uninstallation using Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386354/850848). Which actually uses a code from the [Require an uninstallation password](https://web.archive.org/web/20160416025247/http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Require_an_uninstallation_password) article on the ISXKB.

  Just replace the `InitializeUninstall` with the [`InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup):

  ```pascal
  function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := AskPassword();
  end;
  ```
- Disable the "welcome" page and create a custom welcome-like page after the "password" page.

---