# Inno Setup - Merging implementations of event functions that return boolean (like InitializeSetup)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I use this code to ask for a password:
[Inno Setup - Move the password page before the welcome page (first page)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41462270/850848)

And this code for custom language selector:
[Inno Setup - Language selector with VCL Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41021292/850848)

When I merge them, it does not work.

I need password before that the language selector, so this is no correct:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  Language: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  Language := ExpandConstant('{param:LANG}');
  if Language = '' then
  begin
    Log('No language specified, showing language dialog');
    SelectLanguage();
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Language specified, proceeding with installation');
    Result := AskPassword();
  end;
end;
```

And this way, with an incorrect password the setup continues.

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  Language: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  Language := ExpandConstant('{param:LANG}');
  if Language = '' then
  begin
    Result := AskPassword();
    Log('No language specified, showing language dialog');
    SelectLanguage();
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Language specified, proceeding with installation');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I actually do not really understand, why you complicate the things so much by not asking for language before the password. It would actually make sense. To get a localized password prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Inno Setup 6

Inno Setup 6 has [event attributes](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=eventattributes) features that helps solving this problem.

Just make sure that each of your event implementation have an unique name, e.g. appending unique suffix. And add `event` attribute with the name of the implemented event.

```pascal
[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ...
end;

<event('InitializeSetup')>
function InitializeSetup2(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ...
end;
```

---

## Inno Setup 5

In general, the easiest is to keep both implementations of the event function separate and add one wrapper implementation that call both.

```pascal
function InitializeSetup1(): Boolean;
var
  Language: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  Language := ExpandConstant('{param:LANG}');
  if Language = '' then
  begin
    Log('No language specified, showing language dialog');
    SelectLanguage();
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Language specified, proceeding with installation');
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

function InitializeSetup2(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AskPassword();
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  { Order the calls the way you want the checks to be performed }
  Result :=
    InitializeSetup2() and
    InitializeSetup1();
end;
```

For more general discussion of the problem, see
[Merging event function (InitializeWizard) implementations from different sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40512631/850848)

---

Though in your specific case, it's more complicated, as you will also need to pass the password from the first instance to the other, similarly to how the language is passed from the first instance to the other.

So actually, the `InitializeSetup2` (password) implementation will have to be similar like the `InitializeSetup1` (language), not to ask for the password again.

I actually do not really understand, why you complicate the things so much by not asking for language before the password. It would actually make sense. To get a localized password prompt.